# How to write a synthetic value data formatter using SBSyntheticValueProvider

Tags: python, xcode, debugging, lldb

I have a simple templated C++ class `storage_for<T>` that essentially stores a value of type T in a raw array of characters. I want to implement an lldb data formatter that casts the array of characters to type T and only displays T's members. So let's say I have a variable `storage_for<std::pair<int, int>> s;` then the Xcode variables list should display the nodes

```
s (storage_for<std::pair<int, int>>)
   first = ...
   secon = ...
```

without showing the internals of type `storage_for` and without introduced a fake child element. [From reading the documentation](http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html) I thought the following should work:

```
class storage_for_synth(lldb.SBSyntheticValueProvider): 
    def __init__(self, valobj, internal_dict):
        self.valobj = valobj

    def get_value(self):
        return self.valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('m_buffer').GetChildMemberWithName('__lx').Cast(self.valobj.GetType().GetTemplateArgumentType(0))
```

but it doesn't. The expression in `get_value` itself is correct. But neither the Xcode variables list nor the lldb console display anything at all for variables of my type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like correct behavior

`get_value` is meant to return a value for variables of your type, e.g. if you had

```
class Int {
  private: int m_value;
};
```

You could use `get_value` to make your Int class have the same value as its underlying integer representation

In your case it sounds like you are trying to make an SBValue have the same value as an aggregate type (your underlying T). Aggregate types (i.e. classes) do not have a value in the same way that an int has a value (this is by design - those types have child values)

Hence, LLDB is going to interpreter your instructions as making a type's value be a variable that has no value

What you are going to need to do is vend child values in your provider, and vend them as the child values of your underlying T

On that note, let me quickly warn you that using SBValue::Cast() for non pointer-to-pointer conversions will occasionally not do the right thing (this is a known issue) - I would encourage you to cast m_buffer from a char* to a T* if at all

Comment: To clarify: Do SBValues implement special behavior if they wrap a scalar type like int, double etc vs a non-scalar struct type?

Comment: It's not so much "special" behavior as "different" behavior - scalar types are assumed to have a value, wheres aggregate types are assumed not to have it